# SQL server- Transaction log for database is full

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to insert some data into a table in my database in sql server. It has huge amount of data, I am talking about millions of records.

I kept getting **error 9002**

> The transaction log for database 'GCVS2' is full. To find
>   out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc
>   column in sys.databases.

When I tried inserting data yesterday, it was fine with no problem, although it did take some time.

I tried it again today but kept getting this error. I checked the log file for my database, and it's auto increment is set to 10% ,unlimited. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: similar question asked a gazillion times on SO and internet in general. How come you couldn't find anything???

Comment: set your database to use simple mode instead of full recovery. and then shrink your log file

Comment: Mitch, I did read the threads but to no avail would solve my issue . That's why I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check the `Recovery` mode of your database. Put it in `Full Recovery mode`. After that, make sure there is a `transaction log` backup in place for your database. You will need to dig through it and make a Maintenance plan, depending upon how critical your data is. That will be the long term solution.

For time being you can shrink your log files using following `DBCC` command -

```
BACKUP LOG  DBName WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE (  DBNameLog, 1)
```

Or you can do it through `Object Explorer`. Refer to [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/) link for details. But you will have to set your Database to `Simple Recovery model` to use the `Shrink` command

Answer (score 2):

You Can Truncate the transaction log.  use the below query

```
BACKUP LOG  databasename  WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DBCC SHRINKFILE (  databasename_Log, 1)
```

[Check here for more details](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/03/sql-server-shrinkfile-and-truncate-log-file-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Yes, otherwise he can take a backup disk and truncate